# Using .pre before validation in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'm creating a model called `User`. Nothing new. One of my fields is set as `required` but I want to set it using a `pre` function when saving. Something similar to:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(callback){
    if(this.isNew){
        this.defaultId = this.ids[0];
    }

    callback();
});
```

Only problem is that validation is triggered before `pre` and a validation error is triggered. Is there a way around this. It doesn't have to be `pre` anyway to get this done **within the Schema**  is acceptible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mongoose's `validate` lifecycle event in order to do anything prior to Mongoose's validation. Here's how that would look:

```
UserSchema.pre('validate', function(callback){
    if(this.isNew){
        this.defaultId = this.ids[0];
    }

    callback();
});
```